# How to Prevent a Delay in Display of First Image in Backstretch

Tags: javascript

The following Backstretch script works to display fading random images with captions. 
However, the first image and caption appear only after a five seconds delay after page load, 
or whatever time is set in "setInterval(loadRandomImage, 5000, images);" as if it were "setTimeout."

Please let me know What I'm doing wrong, or should be added to prevent the delay of the first image to display?

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>  
  <script src="/js/jquery.backstretch.captionjs"></script>

<script>

// Preload
$(images).each(function(){
$("<img/>")[0].src = this.url;});

var images = new Array(); //array of imgs objects

images[0] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/l&h.jpg", caption: "Stan Laurel and Oliver Hardy"};
images[1] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/sherlock-watson.jpg", caption: "Basil Rathbone and Nigel Bruce"};
images[2] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/powell-loy.jpg", caption: "William Powell and Myrna Loy"};
images[3] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/conried-bergman-bogart.jpg", caption: "Paul Heinreid, Ingrid Bergman and Humphrey Bogart"};

function loadRandomImage(imgs) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);

    console.log("loadRandomImages(): index = "+ index);

    $.backstretch(imgs[index].url, {fade: 1500, speed: 5000}); 

    $("#caption").html(imgs[index].caption);
}

// Change images every 5 seconds
setInterval(loadRandomImage, 5000, images);

</script>


    <div id="caption"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call your `loadRandomImage` function once on the page load, and then let the interval do the rest.

```js
// Preload
$(images).each(function(){
$("<img/>")[0].src = this.url;});

var images = new Array(); //array of imgs objects

images[0] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/l&h.jpg", caption: "Stan Laurel and Oliver Hardy"};
images[1] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/sherlock-watson.jpg", caption: "Basil Rathbone and Nigel Bruce"};
images[2] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/powell-loy.jpg", caption: "William Powell and Myrna Loy"};
images[3] = {url: "/images/backgrounds/conried-bergman-bogart.jpg", caption: "Paul Heinreid, Ingrid Bergman and Humphrey Bogart"};

function loadRandomImage(imgs) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);

    console.log("loadRandomImages(): index = "+ index);

    $.backstretch(imgs[index].url, {fade: 1500, speed: 5000}); 

    $("#caption").html(imgs[index].caption);
}


// we run the function once at the beginning.
loadRandomImage(images);

// Change images every 5 seconds
setInterval(loadRandomImage, 5000, images);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<div id="caption"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nicolas.

Comment: Calling 'loadRandomImage' function on page load works only to prevent a delay in loading the first image. The caption, however, does not appear on that first image. How can the 5 second delay also be prevented for the first caption?

Comment: Update, @Nicolas: Calling 'loadRandomImage' function on page load works perfectly to load image and caption immediately on page load. I realized it when I moved '<div id="caption"></div>' closer to the <body> tag. Thanks again - You solved it.

Comment: As the script is now, the image already fades in, but I've not been able to get the caption to fade in as well. How can it be done?